# Error: 'nombre' was not declared in tis scope

Tags: c++

Tengo duda con esta tarea se programar en php pero en c++ apenas estoy aprendiendo, El programa me marca un error en la función

> xalan(x,i)
>   **15    24  C:\Users\admin\Documents\tarea8\9\main.cpp  [Error] 'xalan' was not declared in this scope**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
//sin(x)=x-x^3/(3!)+x^5/(5!)+...+(-1)^n(x^(2n+1))/((2n+1)!)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float x,sinx,sinx2;
    printf("\nprograma para calcular sin(x)");
    printf("\nintrodusca el angulo x en radianes \n");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    sinx=x-(x*x*x)/(3*2)+(x*x*x*x*x)/(5*4*3*2)-(x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/(7*6*5*4*3*2)+(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/(9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2);
    printf("\nsin(x)=%f ",sinx);
    sinx2=x;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
        sinx2=sinx2+xalan(x,i);
    printf("\nsin2(x)=%f ",sinx2);
}


float xalan(float x,int n)
{   //(-1)^n(x^(2n+1))/((2n+1)!)
    int fact=2*n+1;
    float xn=1;
    for(int i=(2*n);i>0;i--)
        fact=fact*(i);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    xn=xn*(-1)*(x*x);
    xn=xn*x;
    return xn/(fact);
}
```

Comment: y que error te marca?

Comment: 15 24 C:\Users\admin\Documents\tarea8\9\main.cpp [Error] 'xalan' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sube la declaración de la función **xalan** a antes de main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

float xalan(float x,int n)
{ 
   ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   ...
}
```

El problema es que **xalan** no ha sido cargado por el programa cuando estás intentando llarmarlo.

Comment: muchas disculpa mi ignorancia apenas le ando aprendiendo te lo agradezco

Comment: No te preocupes, muchos sufrimos ese camino

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es que antes de tu main lo declares solo como

float xalan(float x,int n);

Y con eso evitarías mover la implementación de la misma

Answer (score 1):

Te hace falta el prototipo de la función, este se declara antes del main así:

```
float xalan(float x,int n);
```

Los prototipos son necesarios en c++ si se van a declarar las funciones debajo del main.
Si se van a hacer antes del main, no es necesario un prototipo.